# "Присвойте одном из указателей адрес 100, другому - 108. Подсчитайте и выведите разницу между указателями. Обоснуйте полученный ответ"

Tags: c++, указатели

У меня есть задание из лабораторной работы по C++:

> Объявите две переменные типа `int`.
>
> Объявите два указателя типа `int`. Одному указателе присвойте адрес одной из переменных при объявлении, а другому в отдельном операторе.
>
> С помощью указателя измените первой переменной. В коде покажите, что изменение состоялась.
>
> Присвойте одном из указателей адрес `100`, другому — `108`. Подсчитайте и выведите разницу между указателями. Обоснуйте полученный ответ.

Можно ли так присваивать адрес указателям, либо это делается с только помощью операции `&`? Пробовала так, но очень сомневаюсь в правильности:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int c = 1, d = 2;
    int* pc = &c;
    int* pd;
    pd = &d;
    cout << "At first: c = " << c << endl;
    c = *pd;
    cout << "Then: c = " << c << endl;
    *pc = 100;
    *pd = 108;
    cout << pc - pd;
}
```

Comment: Интересно... Посчитать разницу между адресами... А вы что делаете?

Comment: надо убрать звёздочки, верно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Можно ли так присваивать адрес указателям, либо это делается с только
> помощью операции &?

Можно, но требуется приведение типа. Указатель это не число в привычном понимании — это адрес. И с этими адресом можно выполнять различные операции (т.н. арифметика указателей). Литерал 100 интерпретируется как целочисленный тип (`int`), а нам нужно интерпретировать его как указатель на целочисленный тип (`int *`). Можно выполнить привидение в стиле C:

```
pc = (int *) 100;
```

Или в стиле C++ при помощи [reinterpret_cast](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/reinterpret-cast-operator?view=msvc-160):

```
pc = reinterpret_cast<int *>(100);
```

Теперь указатель pc хранит в себе адрес 100 и с ним можно выполнять различные трюки. Например вычитать:

```
int * x_ptr = (int *) 100;
int * y_ptr = (int *) 108;

std::cout << y_ptr - x_ptr << std::endl;
```

Здесь мы получим 2 так как в отличии от обычных арифметических операций, операции над указателями выполняются в контексте размера их типов. Мы знаем, что размер целочисленного обычно 4 байта (посмотреть это можно при помощи специального оператора `sizeof`: `std::cout << sizeof(int);`). Следовательно, манипуляция указателем рассматривается как манипуляция *блоками по 4 байта*. Например:

```
int * x_ptr = (int *) 100;
x_ptr++;
```

Инкремент увеличит адрес не на единицу, а на 4 т.е. в контексте указателя на `sizeof(int)` байт. Если вы вычитаете один указатель из другого, то результат интерпретируется как количество *блоков* в разнице.

`y_ptr - x_ptr` другими словами это `(108 - 100) / sizeof(int)` (*)

---

*Как было сказано в ответе @eanmos и описано в стандарте, этот код попадает под UB. Складывать и вычитать указатели можно, если они указывают либо на `NULL` либо на элементы одно и того же массива. В противном случае возможно неопределенное поведение.*

*Однако, если мы рассматриваем этот код как нечто скомпилированное и запущенное под x86, где указатель адресует на 1 байт, то скорее всего данный код вычислит ожидаемое `2`. В общем, на свой страх и риск.*

Comment: Я бы считал любой компилятор (его определенную версию), который делает что-то невразумительное (UB) с подобным кодом ошибочным и просто не использовал его

Answer (score 4):

Про явное приведение типа при преобразовании целочисленного типа к указательному и особенности арифметики указателей уже написали в других ответах. Хотелось бы добавить несколько слов по поводу возможного неопределённого поведения при преобразовании произвольного целого числа к указательному значению.

Пусть у нас есть две целочисленные константы, которые мы преобразуем к указательному типу, а затем вычисляем разность получившихся указательных значений.

Стандарт языка утверждает ([basic.compound/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3)), что значение указателя — это одно из следующих значений:

- указатель на объект,
- указатель на гипотетический элемент, следующий непосредственно за объектом,
- нулевое указательное значение,
- недействительное указательное значение (*invalid pointer value*).

Какое конкретно значение примет указатель при присваивании ему целого числа определяется реализацией ([expr.reinterpret.cast/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#5)):

> A value of integral type or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to a pointer.
> A pointer converted to an integer of sufficient size (if any such exists on the implementation) and back to the same pointer type will have its original value; **mappings between pointers and integers are otherwise implementation-defined**.

Таким образом, при присвоении указателю произвольного целого числа, он может запросто получить некоторое недействительное указательное значение. Последствия обращения к недействительному указателю определяются реализацией. В частности, в стандарте языка явно оговорено, что простое копирование недействительного указателя может привести к аварийному завершению работы программы ([basic.stc.general/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.general#4)):

> [...] Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior.
> Any other use of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior.28
> 28) Some implementations might define that copying an invalid pointer value causes a system-generated runtime fault.

Если же каким-то образом (чудом? ;)) удалось подобрать такие целочисленные константы, что после их преобразования в указательный тип, получившиеся указатели указывают на некоторые *объекты*, то эти объекты не должны иметь динамический класс памяти (dynamic storage duration). Это связано с тем, что константа в коде не является целочисленным представлением безопасно-наследуемого указателя (*integer representation of a safely-derived pointer*, см.: [basic.stc.dynamic.safety/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic.safety#3)), а значит и получившиеся указатели не являются безопасно-наследуемыми указателями (*safely-derived pointer*, см.: [basic.stc.dynamic.safety/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic.safety#2)). Стандарт языка разрешает реализации считать такие указатели недействительными ([basic.stc.dynamic.safety/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic.safety#4)):

> [...] Alternatively, an implementation may have strict pointer safety, in which case a pointer value referring to an object with dynamic storage duration that is not a safely-derived pointer value is an invalid pointer value unless the referenced complete object has previously been declared reachable ([util.dynamic.safety]).
> [...]
> This is true even if the unsafely-derived pointer value would compare equal to some safely-derived pointer value.

И наконец, полученные указатели, если мы хотим найти их разность, должны указывать на элементы одного и того же массива (или оба нулевые), иначе поведение программы не определено (см.: [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1229324) @eanmos, [expr.add/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#5)).

Как подобрать два целых числа так, чтобы они удовлетворяли всем описанным выше условиям — вопрос, конечно, интересный :)

---

Теперь что касается реальных компиляторов. Мы то знаем, что указатель — по сути просто целое число, представляющее адрес некоторого байта, что все байты идут один за другим линейным образом. Всё довольно прозрачно и никаких неожиданностей произойти не должно. Рассмотрим пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a, b;
    
    cout << (void *)&a << endl;
    cout << (void *)&b << endl;
    cout << std::min(std::uintptr_t(&b) - std::uintptr_t(&a),
                     std::uintptr_t(&a) - std::uintptr_t(&b)) << endl;
    cout << (&a + 1 == &b) << endl; //1 or 0
    cout << (&b + 1 == &a) << endl; //0 or 1
}
```

Здесь мы объявили две переменных `a` и `b` вывели их адреса, и нашли разность адресов между этими переменными (предварительно преобразовав указатели в целые числа, чтобы избежать неопределённого поведения). Зная значения адресов и разность между адресами мы можем судить о результатах вычисления выражений `&a + 1 == &b` и `&b + 1 == &a`: если переменные расположены одна непосредственно за другой, то одно из равенств будет истинным. Стандарт разрешает такое сравнение ([expr.eq/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq#3)):

> [...] Comparing pointers is defined as follows:
> — If one pointer represents the address of a complete object, and another pointer represents the address one past the last element of a different complete object,75 the result of the comparison is **unspecified**.
> 75) As specified in [basic.compound], an object that is not an array element is considered to belong to a single-element array for this purpose.

Хотя результат сравнения неспецифицирован. И понятно почему. Объект `b` может идти непосредственно за объектом `a`, либо наоборот, либо между ними вообще может находиться какой-нибудь другой объект.

Итак, взглянем на результат работы [clang](https://ideone.com/9ezeBF):

```
0x7fff948bf6c7
0x7fff948bf6c6
1
0
1
```

Получили ожидаемый вывод. Объекты действительно расположены впритык и одно из сравнений истинно.

Результат работы [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbabc46e8d3a8149):

```
0x7ffe20fee88e
0x7ffe20fee88f
1
0
0
```

Здесь два объекта также расположены впритык, один следует непосредственно за другим. Но результат обоих сравнений — **`false`**! Да, g++ считает, что если объект `b` следует непосредственно за объектом `a`, то указатель за конец объекта `a` не обязан успешно сравниваться с указателем на объект `b`. Несмотря на все наши знания об окружении, компилятор повёл себя контринтуитивным образом, и он имеет на это право, ибо `the result of the comparison is unspecified`.

Эти примеры я привёл для того, чтобы показать, что по-возможности не следует полагаться на поведение, определяемое реализацией, и уж тем более следует избегать неопределённого поведения. Кто знает, может внутри оптимизатора зашита проверка вида "если значение указателя меньше 128 или значение указателя равно 1000000009, то считать такой указатель гарантированно невалидным".

---

P.S. Весьма необычно повёл себя [vc++](https://rextester.com/MXXKV7916):

```
00000093AF42FAF4
00000093AF42FAF2
2
0
0
```

Он просто вставил дополнительный байт между двумя переменными, поэтому оба сравнения были ложны. Переписав их так (теперь здесь есть UB): `&a + 2 == &b` и `&b + 2 == &a` получил следующий [вывод](https://rextester.com/NZX65203):

```
000000ADF3E4FAE5
000000ADF3E4FAE2
3
0
0
```

Компилятор старается добиться одинакового результата при сравнении, раздвигая переменные в памяти :)

---

P.P.S.

Есть ещё небольшое различие при приведении целочисленного литерала со значением `0` к указательному типу при использовании приведения в стиле C (а также функциональном стиле) и с использованием `reinterpret_cast`.

Приведение в стиле C сперва попытается преобразовать литерал с помощью `static_cast`, и это преобразование сработает, т.к. существует неявное преобразование из нулевой указательной константы целочисленного типа (*null pointer constant of integral type*) в указательный тип. Результат — нулевое указательное значение. См.: [conv.ptr/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.ptr#1).

С другой стороны, `reinterpret_cast` отображает целочисленные значения в указательные определяемым реализацией образом: не гарантируется, что целочисленное значение ноль (в частности, литерал `0`) будет преобразовано в нулевое указательное значение ([expr.reinterpret.cast/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#9)):

> [...] a null pointer constant of integral type is not necessarily converted to a null pointer value.

Существуют машины, на которых нулевые указатели не состоят полностью из нулевых бит: [comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 5.17](http://www.c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html).

Comment: А теперь добавьте сравнение `cout << addr_eql(&a + 1, &b) << endl; //1 or 0`  с вот такой внешней функцией `int addr_eql (char *a, char *b) {
  return a == b;
}` и вы поймете, что `g++` сломан (похоже уже безнадежно?)

Comment: Наверное, raw pointers это зло в некоторой степени :-)

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, зло -- это скорее сами кресты, ломающие мозги его разработчиков

Answer (score 3):

Оба существующих ответа, как и само задание из вопроса, некорректны и содержат неопределенное поведение.

---

Согласно стандарту C++, вычитание двух указателей возможно тогда и только тогда, когда они указывают на элементы одного и того же массива или являются нулевыми указателями:

> <sup>(5)</sup> When two pointer expressions `P` and `Q` are subtracted, the type of the result is an implementation-defined signed integral type; this type shall be the same type that is defined as `std::ptrdiff_t` in the `<cstddef>` header (17.2.4).
>
> <sup>(5.1)</sup> — If `P` and `Q` both evaluate to null pointer values, the result is 0.
>
> <sup>(5.2)</sup> — Otherwise, if `P` and `Q` point to, respectively, array elements `i` and `j` of the same array object `x`, the expression `P - Q` has the value `i − j`.
>
> <sup>(5.3)</sup> — Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
>
> [ISO/IEC N486](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/releases/download/n4868/n4868.pdf) — § 7.6.6

---

В языке C такие трюки тоже являются неопределенным поведением:

> <sup>(9)</sup> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements.
>
> ISO/IEC 9899:2017 — § 6.5.6

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл, идемте в [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118281/https-ru-stackoverflow-com-q-1228843-185348).

Answer (score 2):

1. Указатели нужно объявить, вы же занимаетесь не понятно чем
2. Указателям нужно указать на адрес
3. Указатели нужно вычесть

```
int main()
{
    int* pc;
    int* pd;
    
    pc = reinterpret_cast<int*> (0x64);
    pd = reinterpret_cast<int*> (0x6C);
    std::cout << pd - pc;
    return 0;
}
```

Разобраться что и почему он выдает уже на вашей совести.

Comment: @pchela Вы пытаетесь указателям ,указывающим на NULL, присвоить значение 100 и 108. Ваша же задача изменить адреса на которые они указывают

Comment: Я бы акцентировал внимание на том факте, что для присвоения указателю целого числа необходимо явное приведение типа. По-моему на этом моменте автор вопроса и застопорился, когда компилятор стал ругаться на код `pc = 100;`.

Comment: Кстати десятичные числа `100` и `108` в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления - это `0x64` и `0x6C`.

Comment: Минус мой за неопределенное поведение.